# Newly added field to index not working

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce, indexing

I am adding a field to an index. I want to add **No Bathrooms** field.

This is my Business tool

[image: business tool]

This is the template

[image: template]

I have added the field in sitecore_web_index and sitecore_master_index inside PlugIn.Search.Solr.PolicySet-1.0.0 file

```
      {
        "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrIndexFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr",
        "Name": "PropertyDetailsBaths",
        "Type": "System.String",
        "TypeHint": "string"
      },
```

Created a patch file to add a new field

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement" search:require="solr">
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="propertydetailsbaths" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" returnType="string" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
           </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
```

I can see the field using showadmin.aspx

[image: admin/showconfig.aspx]

I have created a Bathroom facet to test the new field but its not showing any result. I have re-indexed, restarted IIS and cleared all cache.

Am I missing any steps?

How can I see the newly added field in Solr?

Comment: Try to follow this blog - https://raghvendracodes.wordpress.com/2020/09/14/sitecore-commerce-9-3-adding-a-custom-filed-to-the-solr-index-for-a-sellable-item/

Comment: I feel the handler is missing.
Please check the following Sitecore Documentation link: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/adding-a-property-field-to-an-index.html#UUID-ac07f9ec-4d0c-a118-9b91-3147c7990306_section-5dc18cbd48ad5-idm46079268764240_body Let me know if it helps.